Woodbury matrix identity with a minus sign
Is there a form of Woodbury matrix identity
$(A + UCV )^{-1} = A^{-1} - A^{-1}U (C^{-1} + VA^{-1}U )^{-1} VA^{-1}$
But with a minus sign? i.e. $(A - UCV )^{-1}$ It seems like I have to painfully decompose $C$ here ..

Rewrite the inverse that you're trying to calculate as $(A + U(-C)V)^{-1}$, and note that $(-C)^{-1} = -C^{-1}$.
